# Getting phone number of store from Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api, geolocation

I want to extract some data from Google Maps, I tried before with OSM but the result doesn't satisfy me enough.

What I need exactly, is there any way to take the data description from a feature on Google Maps like "phone number from some store".

Comment: Please describe what you tried, how the result is not satisfactory, how you imagine your final workflow and what your research yielded.

Comment: I downloaded data from "open street map" but I could not find the data I need, such as the phone numbers of the stores, It only gave me incomplete data when I looked inside the data, Some data don't even have a name!

Comment: What did you expect from a free, open source service with data added by volunteers? Feel free to contribute, if you're that unsatisfied. This still leaves the second part of my question.

Comment: I mean the "data"not the people who provide the service!

Comment: Please get familiar with the concept of OSM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8722558/9778755) has a good answer to this question. Basically it involves these steps:

1. Get an API key for the [**Google Places API**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/overview)
2. Use **Place Search** request
3. Use returned token in a **Place Details** request
4. Retrieve `formatted_phone_number` and `international_phone_number`